# Oracle Mathematical Expression Parsing

Tags: oracle, parsing, math

I have a process that creates very long mathematical expressions in Oracle as a mechanism to run calculations.

It is there, because it runs against our data.  I'm saying that because that's the reason its there and we don't want to run outside the database for performance reasons.

However, users now are generating multiple calculation expressions, and are having problems with divide by zero in part of the expression.  Sadly, they want to have behavior in these calculations where 3/0 = 0, so it doesn't halt the rest of the calculation.  Even though its technically incorrect.

Here's an example of something where they want to see a 1:

```
SELECT (3/0)+1 FROM DUAL
```

I had suggested wrapping divisions in a function, but was told that was too difficult for the users and that should be handled on the backend.

I see no overloading or overriding of Oracle operators, so that leaves me with parsing complex expressions, finding the Divide operations and finding the numerator and denominating of those expressions and doing a replace most likely with my function (considering things like nested calculations, etc).

Does anyone have any suggestions on that or other alternatives?  As you can see from the thread, I provided users other suggestions, but have been pigeonholed.

Ideally, I want to convert any expression like this:

```
SELECT (3/0)+1 FROM DUAL
```

Into

```
SELECT DIVIDE(3,0)+1 FROM DUAL
```

Keeping in mind it might be part of a very complex parse tree, rather than the simple example you see.

Comment: All I can say is, "good luck with that!" I don't understand the part about not wanting to go outside the database "for performance reasons". The database obviously is not optimized for parsing algebraic expressions; what makes one think that staying within the db (and forcing it to do things that are very unnatural for a db) will be "more performant" than going outside the db? Also the thing about division by 0 is fishy; how are you supposed to handle the cases where a user does NOT want division by 0 to result in 0, but in an error (as it should)?

Comment: performance reasons concerning selecting the data...if they have 50 data points in a calc..we want the database to return 1 value...not 50 and have a middle tier...they dont want the div by zero error...that's the challenge i have to figure out

Comment: You don't need the data to leave the db. You need to take the algebraic expression (presumably a string), send it outside the db, let any parser you can find process it and send it back to the db where it can then access data.

Comment: i might be open to that...although that will require more changes to our process...the front end is .NET

Comment: Oracle tries to cache SQL statements and their exec plans for future re-use. Your approach will waste plenty of RAM in shared pool.

Comment: the expression isnt going to look different each time its run...it just wont look like the original...ive simplified the issue to focus on my question...but what your mention for large scale reasons that i haven't explained...isnt really a concern

Comment: Sounds like a very bad idea to me.

Comment: Point your users to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero and ask them if, even if it were possible, what it would mean to allow a division by zero.